# Why a covered count query need still to fetch and examine documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I don't understand why a count query fetches documents into memory even though an index exists which should cover the query. The problem is that such a query can take more than one hour in production. It slows down the whole database because lot of data needs to be read from disk (75-100 MB/sec while the query is running). The used index in production is about 5 GB on each mongodb node. The total size of all indexes in production is 32 GB and fits perfectly in RAM since each node has 128 GB RAM.

I broke down the problem to a **minimalistic, unsharded setup**. I inserted the following types of documents:

1. 3 documents without both fields `shopId` and `missingSince`
2. 5 documents with field `shopId:1` without field `missingSince`
3. 7 documents with field `shopId:1` and `missingSince:null`
4. 13 documents with field `shopId:1` and
   `missingSince:ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z")`

I created the **non-sparse** index `{shopId:1, missingSince:1}`.
The execution plan of the query `count({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null})` indicated `"totalDocsExamined" : 12` which means that 12 documents had to be fetched. These must be the 5 documents of point 2 plus the 7 documents of point 3. All these 12 documents should be in the index with `shopId:1, missingSince:null`, thus satisfying the query.

*But why does mongodb still need to fetch and examine these 12 documents?*

Here is my test collection:

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.offer.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 4, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 6, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 7, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 9, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 10, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 11, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 12, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 13, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 14, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 15, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 16, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 17, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 18, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 19, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 20, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 21, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 22, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 23, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 24, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 25, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 26, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 27, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 28, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
```

Here is the output of explain():

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.offer.explain(true).count({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null})
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.offer",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shopId" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "shopId" : 1,
                        "missingSince" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "shopId_1_missingSince_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "shopId" : [
                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                        ],
                        "missingSince" : [
                            "[null, null]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 12,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 12,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 13,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 12,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 12,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 12,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 13,
                "advanced" : 12,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 12,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 12,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 13,
                    "advanced" : 12,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 0,
                    "restoreState" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "shopId" : 1,
                        "missingSince" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "shopId_1_missingSince_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "shopId" : [
                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                        ],
                        "missingSince" : [
                            "[null, null]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 12,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Kays MacBook Pro",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.6",
        "gitVersion" : "05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody could find a valid reason for this issue, I opened yesterday a mongodb bug report: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29326

Mongodb engineers confirmed that's a bug. Unfortunately it's not mentioned in mongodb's documentation which would have saved us many hours tracing down the issue and deploy another schema design from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with that specific query is that, you are searching NULL values. If you change that null in query to ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z") you will get wanted result (everything comes from index).

Build your query with projection where you disable _id.

```
db.offer.find({"shopId":1, "missingSince":ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z")},{_id:0,shopId:1,missingSince:1}).explain(true)
```

Because, _id is included always to result, **except** IF you disable it. To get that _id (what is not included to your index) mongo MUST go to the disk to read it.

Comment: This does not change anything. You can check it by running `db.offer.explain(true).find({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null},{_id:0,shopId:1,missingSince:1}).count();` which will show you that still 12 documents had to be fetched: `"totalDocsExamined" : 12`

Comment: You are right.. I didn't remember that searching null values is little bit tricky operation... Changed my answer little bit!

Comment: I know that the query is covered with non-null values, hence my question why this specific query with null-values is not covered. I couldn't find any information in the link that you've provided what one need to change to get null values from the index. Could you be more specific please? Btw. your assumption about the projection is not true for count queries. You can check it by running `db.offer.explain(true).count({"shopId":1, "missingSince":ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z")});` which will show you that 0 documents had to be examined: `"totalDocsExamined" : 0`

Comment: Reason why querying null value generates disk read is because from index point of view, there is no different for  "missing field" or field with null value. Mongo must go to the disk to see if field exists or not. Note, if you really want to find missingSince:null, you should query "missingSince":{ $type: 10 }, because this result won't include documents where "missingSince" is "missing"..

Comment: db.offer.find({"shopId":1, "missingSince":{ $type: 10 }},{_id:0,shopId:1,missingSince:1}).explain(true).executionStats.executionStages.nReturned = 7 VS. db.offer.find({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null},{_id:0,shopId:1,missingSince:1}).explain(true).executionStats.executionStages.nReturned = 12

Comment: my query is **not** using `$type:10` as you suggested because it has to return all documents for the given `shopId` which either don't have the field `missingSince` or is set to null. Since both cases are identical for the index (both are `missingSince:null` in the index), mongodb has no reason to fetch the document to see whether the field exists or not because the query wants to match both cases.
That's why I have opened a mongodb bug report yesterday which mongodb engineers confirmed to be a bug. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29326